# How can I pass a list of values to a block within a resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-datastream

I am trying to set up a Datastream connection from MySQL to BigQuery using Terraform ([docs here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/datastream_stream#nested_mysql_databases)). The docs show this structure for specifying which tables to include:

```
resource "google_datastream_stream" "default" {
    depends_on = [
        google_kms_crypto_key_iam_member.key_user
    ]
    stream_id = "my-stream"
    desired_state = "NOT_STARTED"
    location = "us-central1"
    display_name = "my stream"
    labels = {
        key = "value"
    }
    source_config {
        source_connection_profile = google_datastream_connection_profile.source_connection_profile.id
        mysql_source_config {
            include_objects {
                mysql_databases {
                    database = "my-database"
                    mysql_tables {
                        table = "includedTable"
                        mysql_columns {
                            column = "includedColumn"
                            data_type = "VARCHAR"
                            collation = "utf8mb4"
                            primary_key = false
                            nullable = false
                            ordinal_position = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I want to specify several tables to include not just one. Further info in the docs say:

```
The mysql_databases block supports:

database - (Required) Database name.

mysql_tables - (Optional) Tables in the database. Structure is documented below.

The mysql_tables block supports:

table - (Required) Table name.

mysql_columns - (Optional) MySQL columns in the schema. When unspecified as part of include/exclude objects, includes/excludes everything. Structure is documented below.
```

So it says the mysql_databases block is where I pass in the all the tables I want to include but the example syntax only shows how to pass one table like `table = "myTable"`. How can I pass a list of values here or something like that? I'm quite new to Terraform so maybe I'm missing something standard functionality. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution to dynamically create nested blocks:

```
  dynamic "<block_name>" {
    for_each = toset(var.<your-var>)
    content {
      <thing> = <block_name>.value
    }
  }
```